# Spring data JpaRepository, CrudRepository "void delete(ID id);" is not invoked

Tags: spring-data

I tried to delete entity using `repository.delete(id)` using its ID. Entity's ID is `Long` , so changed the generic to `<Entity, Long>`. Then if I try calling `delete` using my entity's id, no exception is thrown, no delete query was also fired as per hibernate logs. But if Use `delete(entity)` it is deleting properly. what could be the reason? I had to implement `@Modifying delete` query as an workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This was a defect that got fixed in one of the recent releases. I am unable to find exact JIRA link and release.

Comment: That's strange. I never found any such reference anywhere. It could be better if anybody can point to such reference. Now I implemented using @modifying which i assume is normally not a good idea.